# Error on resizing image with Intervention, Laravel: Argument 1 passed to Imagine\Gd

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to use resize function of Intervention class, but I got this error:

`Type error: Argument 1 passed to Imagine\Gd\Image::resize() must be an instance of Imagine\Image\BoxInterface, string given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mycms/app/Http/Controllers/UploadsController.php on line 47`

my code:

```
\Image::make($uploaded_filename)->resize(200,200)->move(public_path('items'),'300.'.$name);
```

$uploaded_filename file exists - it is a jpg image. Laravel 5.3, Intervention 2.3, MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are calling global `Image`class instead the `Facade` provided by `Intervention`.

Instead do

```
use Intervention\Image\Image;
```

On top of the page after `namespacing`
and use it like

```
Image::make($uploaded_filename)->resize(200,200)->move(public_path('items'),'300.'.$name);
```

without the backslash (\).

More on [Integration in Laravel](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel)

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. I made the alias word to avoid global class if so, but didin't helped also. I'm using backslash in all my laravel classes, without them none classes has been found. Maybe my installation is wrong... I think I'm going to delete this question, because of too many diffusion, plus installed ImageMagick and it works... Thank you bro!!!

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't helped you. But don't delete the question. I think you have here is a special situation and many would comment on this eventually. After all we all here to ask questions and answer them :) Just keep it and see what happens. And I'd like to suggest to open up another question mentioning that backslash issue. I thinks it worth looking into. I have used Laravel quite some time and I didn't faced such issue personally. But the community may have something else to say. Best of Luck!

Comment: oh, thanks @Gayan. I will create question about this backslash. It is interesting what happens there :)